# Difference between GNN and sparsely connected feedforward NN

Tags: neural-networks, sparse, graph-neural-network

What characteristics differentiate a classic GNN and a sparsely connected feedforward NN (basically a modified fully-connected NN), where the sparse connectivity is given by a user-defined sparsity matrix?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it very complicated you can probably write an MLP that works similarly for a particular graph configuration. However, MLP are not permutation invariant with respect to nodes. Even if you change the ordering of the sparsity matrix you would also have to permute the weights within the MLP as well.